# Нужно ли ставить тире перед вторым «как»?

Tags: пунктуация, тире

*"Урнакоша" иногда переводится как "прядь волос меж бровями", но чаще (—) как "третий глаз".*
Нужно ли ставить тире по правилам или здесь оно может быть исключительно как авторский знак?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тире ставится в неполном предложении, являющемся частью сложного предложения, когда пропущенный член (обычно сказуемое) восстанавливается из предшествующей части фразы и в месте пропуска делается пауза, например:
*Они стояли друг против друга. Олег — растерянный и смущенный, Нина — с выражением вызова на лице* (Фадеев); *Его деревянные львы были похожи на толстых собак, а нереиды — на торговок рыбой* (К. Паустовский).
При отсутствии паузы тире не ставится, например: *Егорушка долго оглядывал его, а он Егорушку* (Чехов).
[Тире в неполном предложении](http://lingvotech.com/tire_v_nepolnom_predlozhenii)

**"Урнакоша" иногда переводится как "прядь волос меж бровями", но чаще** [переводится] **— как "третий глаз".**

Ставить тире или не ставить — это, конечно, дело автора. Я бы поставила, потому что в предложении "куча" кавычек и третий глаз на этом фоне (без тире) совершенно теряется. Я бы его выделила.